# On the probability and expectation of rolling 3 dice and get 4, 5, 6

Tags: probability, expected-value, dice

I am looking at the following questions on rolling 3 dice at the same time:

1. Probability of getting 4, 5, 6 without particular order;
2. If get a result different from 4, 5, 6, then roll again. What is the expectation of number of rolls;
3. If get a result different from 4, 5, 6, then roll the dice which is not in the set {4, 5, 6} again, e.g. first roll gives 4, 5, 1, then roll the third dice only until get a 6. What is the expectation of number of rolls.

I am stuck with the third part and do not know how to approach to such question. For the first one, I get the probability $= \left( \frac{1}{6} \right)^3 \times 3\,! = \frac{1}{36}$. And the second question, I use the mean of a geometric distribution and get the expectation $=36$.

Comment: I don't think you can get $7$ on a normal die.

Comment: @Kyky, thanks for pointing it out. It should be 4, 5, 1 actually.

Comment: @VanTom Then please edit the question, setting 4, 5, 1 instead of the irritating 4, 5, 7. (It is of course a good joke, but every one reading the question will remain there more than you want  to.)

Comment: Point 3, one question, to be sure that my answer was the answer to the intention in the question. If the first roll is 4, 4, 2, then we keep one 4, and furher roll two dice to fill in the "remained two places" with the values 5, 6. If in a further roll we get 2, 6, then we keep the 6, and further roll one die till it shows the remained needed 5. Is it so?

Comment: @dan_fulea Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model is a Markov chain with four states, $0,1,2,3$. The state $0$ is the initial state. The final state is $3$.
(The state $k$ means roughly "$k$ matched positions".)

We associate the following constellations to the three states:

- $0$ stays for something like $\{*,*,*\}$ where $*$ is some face not under $4,5,6$. This convention for the $*$ will be used below.
- $1$ stays for something like $\{4,*,*\}$, for $\{5,*,*\}$ and for $\{6,*,*\}$ .
- $2$ stays for something like $\{4,5,*\}$, for $\{4,6,*\}$ and for $\{5,6,*\}$ .
- $3$ stays for the final state $\{4,5,6\}$ .

(Set delimiters are not really precise, because the roll $1,2,1$ may lead to interpretations when written as $\{1,2,1\}$, but something like $4,*,*$ between set delimiters means *a four in some place, then further two no longer useful values (including a possible further occurence of the four, which became useless)*.)

The passage from one state to the other is given by the scheme:

```
     --- 1/36-----------------
    /                         \
   --- 5/12 ----------         \
  /            _1/18__\_________\
 /            /        \         \
[0] -----> [1] -----> [2] -----> [3]
/ \  2/3   / \  1/2   / \  1/6   / \
\_/        \_/        \_/        \_/
1/8        4/9        5/6         1
```

Let $N_k$ the expected number of rolls needed to pass from the state $k$ to the final state $3$. Then $N_3=0$. Else, $N_k>0$, so we make one step, and get a new state $n$ with the specified passing probabilities, from there we expect $N_n$ steps.

The system is:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
N_0 &= 1 + \frac 18N_0+\frac {37}{72}N_1+\frac 13N_2+\frac 1{36}N_3\ ,\\
N_1 &= 1 + \frac 49N_1+\frac 12N_2+\frac 1{18}N_3\ ,\\
N_2 &= 1 + \frac 56N_2+\frac 16N_3\ ,\\
N_3 &=0\ .
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
We solve this system, the solution is:

- $N_3=0$, clear,
- $N_2=6$, of course,
- $N_1=36/5=7.2$,
- $\color{red}{N_0=268/35\approx 7.6571428571428\dots}$ , which is the number asked in the OP.

---

Some words on the computed passage probabilities $p_{kn}$ from the state $k$ to the state $n$.

- $p_{00}$ is $\frac 36\cdot\frac 36\cdot\frac 36=\left(\frac 12\right)^3=\frac 18$.
- $p_{01}$ is computed as follows. We have three "empty places" to fill in with dice results, we are doing this in a strict order, one by one, and can have the possibilities (hit, - , -) and (-, hit, -) and (-, -, hit). It is important to have the order, because (hit, -, -) would mean a hit on the first place, say it is a $4$, then on the second place a $4$ is no longer a hit. So $(4,4,1)$ is in the first set of possibilities. But not in the second one. Then for the three cases we have in sum
  $$
  p_{01}
  =
  \frac 36\cdot\frac 46\cdot\frac 46+
  \frac 36\cdot\frac 36\cdot\frac 46+
  \frac 36\cdot\frac 36\cdot\frac 36\\
  =\frac 3{6^3}(16+12+9)
  =\frac{37}{72}\ .
  $$
- $p_{03}$ is $\frac 36\cdot\frac 26\cdot\frac 16=\frac 1{36}$.
- $p_{02}$ is the difference... Or we can build the cases (hit, hit, -) and (hit, -, hit) and (-, hit, hit) with the same order condition, then count
  $$
  p_{02}
  =
  \frac 36\cdot\frac 26\cdot\frac 56+
  \frac 36\cdot\frac 46\cdot\frac 26+
  \frac 36\cdot\frac 36\cdot\frac 26
  \\=
  \frac 1{6^3}\cdot 3\cdot 2(5+4+3)
  =\frac {12}{36}=\frac 13\ .
  $$
- $p_{11}$ is $\frac 46\cdot\frac 46=\left(\frac 23\right)^2=\frac 49$.
- $p_{13}$ is $\frac 26\cdot\frac 16=\frac 1{18}$.
- $p_{12}$ is the difference... or we can count separately the probabilities when the hit is on the first position, then on the second position, i.e. (hit, -) and (-, hit) getting $\frac 26\cdot\frac 56+\frac 46\cdot\frac 26=\frac2{36}(5+4)=\frac 12$.
- $p_{22}$ is $\frac 56$, and the rest is $p_{23}$.

---

Let us simulate. This is the best test.
(Sage code is following.)

```
import random
N = 10^6
STEPS = 0

R = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

roll = {1: cartesian_product([R]),
        2: cartesian_product([R, R]),
        3: cartesian_product([R, R, R]), }

for _ in range(N):
    still_needed = {4,5,6}
    while still_needed:
        STEPS += 1
        k = 3 - len(still_needed)
        dice = random.choice( roll[3-k] )
        still_needed = still_needed.difference(dice)
        
print("Statistic average: %s" % (STEPS/N).n())
```

And this time i've got:

```
Statistic average: 7.65439500000000
```

which is not far away from the obtained value $268/35\approx 7.65714285714286\dots$

OK, two more time the same simulation, since i do not like the deviation:

```
Statistic average: 7.65246400000000
Statistic average: 7.64682600000000
```

(One may compute the variance using similar methods.)

Answer (score 1):

### **For the 3rd question**:

**(This solution assumes each dice rolled will count as one roll, e.g. throwing 3 dice at the same time will count as 3 rolls)**

The expected number of rolls before getting 4, 5 and 6 on three separate dice with re-rolls for the dice not having 4, 5 or 6 can be viewed as throwing one dice several times until each number has been accounted ones (you just take away the dice that gets a suitable number then move to the next dice). A solution is:
\begin{equation}
E_3 = 1 +\frac{3}{6}*E_2+\frac{3}{6}*E_3\\
E_2 = 1+\frac{2}{6}*E_1+\frac{4}{6}*E_2\\
E_1 = 1+\frac{1}{6}*E_0+\frac{5}{6}*E_1\\
E_0 = 0
\end{equation}
where $E_3$ is the expected throws to get all three numbers, $E_2$ is the expected throws to get two of the numbers, $E_1$ is the expected throws to get the last missing number and $E_0$ is the expected number if you already got them all ($=0$, if you already got  4, 5 and 6 then you don't need to throw more). The fraction before each expected value indicates the probability of moving forward to that step. The 1 in the beginning is the throw that you just did. This equation can now be solved from the bottom up

\begin{equation}
E_1 = 6\\
E_2 = 9\\
E_3 = 11
\end{equation}

So the expected number of rolls if you're missing all {4, 5 and 6} is 11 throws, the expected number if you're missing just 2 values is 9 throws, and the expected number if you're missing just one value is 6 throws.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please explain how do you get the expression for $E_1$ in detail?

Comment: Sure. E_1 is the expected number of throws to get the last digit on the dice. When you throw the dice there are two outcomes, 1) you get the dice that you want and you are done or 2) you don't get the dice that you want and you have to start over again.
The $\frac{1}{6}$ is the probability that you get the number you want and then you're done. The $\frac{5}{6}$ is the probability that you don't, in which case you need to do $E_1$ over again. The +1 in the beginning is the throw that you take, as every time you do this you need to throw the dice once.